# How to add new table to database in the Django application

Tags: django, database

I'm working on Django project and I need certain users to be able to add a new table to existing database from the application admin panel. Since I don't know specificity of products users would like to add to application over time, I need a way for them to just click "add new category" which will become the name of new table in database and inside add category parameters (column names in database) and after clicking "save" it will add such table to database on running application, and other category of users will be able to add products to this category by providing the data for "category parameters".

Since I have no idea how to do it in django, I kindly ask for your help.

Comment: Usually adding new tables is an horrible idea. What you want is more probably adding a row in a table called category and then having another table holding the category parameters.

Comment: @Dave Plug adding new tables isn't always a bad idea, but in this case it isn't the right choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to add a new table for every category. Instead, use a `Product` model with a foreign key to a `Category` model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category =  models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

This way, adding a new "table" is just a matter of entering a new row in the `Category` table. If you want to restrict a category to a user then you can add a `created_by` field on the `Category` model and base your access logic on it.

Note that `on_delete=models.PROTECT` on the foreign key means you can't delete a category as long as there are still products that use that category.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems I'm not thinking well today. Solution was obvious yet I needed someone else to help. Once again thank you and sorry to bother with such simple question.

Comment: @Uzzy don't worry, it happens to everyone :)